# jQuery Datepicker - Automatically define altField for all datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

All my datepickers have an automatically-generated hidden field which has the same ID as the datepicker input, but with an underscore prepended.

```
<div class="datepicker">
    <input id="MyField1" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="_MyField1" type="hidden" value="" />
</div>

<div class="datepicker">
    <input id="MyField2" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="_MyField2" type="hidden" value="" />
</div>
```

And then any field which has class `datepicker` gets made into a datepicker.

```
$('.datepicker input').datepicker({
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    constrainInput: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/y',
    minDate: '+0d',
    numberOfMonths: 2
});
```

But how can I also automatically get it to set the altField option for each one?

This doesn't work.  I also tried doing the assignment in the original options but that doesn't work either.

```
$('.datepicker input').each(function() {
    var altField = '_' + $(this).prop('id');
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'altField', altField);
});
```

Comment: `var altField = '_' + $(this).prop('id');`: note that id is an attribute, not a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [altField](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) option takes a selector, a jQuery object or an element, not an `id` attribute.

Try specifying an [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
$(this).datepicker("option", "altField", "#_" + $(this).prop("id"));
```

Or alternatively, saving a call to `$()` and a call to `prop()`:

```
$(this).datepicker("option", "altField", "#_" + this.id);
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.datepicker input').each(function() {
    var altField = '#_' + $(this).prop('id');
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'altField', altField);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Datapicker 1.9, Using altField, altFormat options and overriding internal method

Clone field to store actual value in database format "yy-mm-dd",
and use main field to display formatted value ("dd-mm-yy" in this sample):

```
$(function() {
    var _connectDatepicker = $.datepicker._connectDatepicker;
    $.datepicker._connectDatepicker = function(target, inst) {
        var $target = $(target);
        var $altField = $target.clone(false).appendTo($target.parent()).hide();
        inst.settings.altField = $altField;
        inst.settings.dateFormat = inst.settings.altFormat = "yy-mm-dd";

        _connectDatepicker.call(this, target, inst);
        $target.removeAttr("name").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
    };
});
```

Comment: In sample above REPLACE
    var $altField = $target.clone(false).appendTo($target.parent()).hide();
TO
    var $altField = $("#_" + $target.prop("id"));