# Dynamic forms and JQuery UI date input

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a form where you can input some information and click a button which will add a replica of that form, this can be done over and over again until they are happy with the information placed.

On this form, I have two date inputs, one which is date_from and another which is date_to, these are arrays to enable more forms on this page. What I am having trouble with, is I'm using JQuery's datepicker UI and at the minute, the inputs have id's so the datepicker can only be used once.

How would I get it so that the JQuery datepicker can be used on each date input which comes up?

This is my code so far...

```
$(function() {
    $("#to-date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        altField: "#alt-to",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});

    $("#from-date").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        altField: "#alt-from",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

Here's [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsV6u/1/), although the datepicker isn't working on this, but it is on my desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to select the inputs.

```
<input type="text" id="from-date"  class="from_date" value="">

$(".from_date").datepicker({...});
```

**Edit**
With the updates (through the comment on my answer) question I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881565/jquery-datepicker-automatically-define-altfield-for-all-datepickers).

You can use JQuery selectors in the altField to get to the input you want the date to be shown in.

Comment: That doesn't work, as I have a hidden field which it's meant to update and using just one updates all of the hidden fields relevant to the field which was clicked on.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the mention about there are hidden fields within the form as well. Everytime someone clicks on the add a form button it will give out two fields which can be seen and two which are hidden. I need the two which can be seen to update the two hidden fields corresponding to the two which you see. This needs to be completely dynamic some how.

Comment: Then I think you'll find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881565/jquery-datepicker-automatically-define-altfield-for-all-datepickers)

Comment: Thank you for that comment, it has helped me out. :)